# How to extract nested ternaries into independent statement

Tags: c#

I am not familiar with nested ternaries. I will like to extract this
into independent statement. Any ideas ?

```
        Status = response.Item1 ? task.IsCleanupTask ? "Completed" : "New" : "Error"
```

Comment: It's exactly like a nested if-else. `if (condition1) { if (condition 2) return_1; else return 2} else {return 3}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Version using only nested if-else**

This code is the same as:

```
if ( response.Item1 )
  if ( task.IsCleanupTask )
    Status = "Completed";
  else
    Status = "New";
else 
  Status = "Error";
```

Or if you prefer:

```
if ( response.Item1 )
{
  if ( task.IsCleanupTask )
  {
    Status = "Completed";
  }
  else
  {
    Status = "New";
  }
}
else
{
  Status = "Error";
}
```

**Version mixing one if-else and one ternary operator**

Also as [@Pierre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67494364/12031933) indicated:

```
if ( response.Item1 )
  Status = task.IsCleanupTask ? "Completed" : "New";
else
  Status = "Error";
```

**Version with nested ternary operators with brackets**

You can write this nested to be more comprehensible as:

```
Status = response.Item1 ? ( task.IsCleanupTask ? "Completed" : "New" ) : "Error";
```

**Version with nested ternary operators formatted on multiple lines**

You can employ the style I like and use often especially with long lines:

```
Status = response.Item1 
         ? task.IsCleanupTask 
           ? "Completed" 
           : "New"
         : "Error";

Status = response.Item1 
         ? task.IsCleanupTask ? "Completed" : "New"
         : "Error";
```

[?: operator (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

[Ternary and Nested Ternary Operators in C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2350b6/ternary-and-nested-ternary-operator-in-C-Sharp/)

Answer (score 1):

```
if item1 is true then
  task.IsCleanupTask ? "Completed" : "New"
else "Error"
```

also said

```
if item1 is true then
  if IsCleanupTask is true
    Completed
  else
    New
else
  Error
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = task.IsCleanupTask ? "Completed" : "New";
Status = response.Item1 ? a : "Error"
```

I have pulled out the inner-ternary into its own variable.

Answer (score 0):

Nested ternaries are usually an indication that a value state is complicated enough to justify it's own function. In my experience, the best way to write `Status = response.Item1 ? task.IsCleanupTask ? "Completed" : "New" : "Error"` is to extract it to...

```
private String getStatus(Response response, Task task) {
  if(!response.Item1)
    return "Error"


  if(task.IsCleanupTask)
    return "Completed"


  return "New"
}
```

This is by far the most legible, and the easiest to modify form for the future you/dev. The reason you put it in a function first instead of writing it out as nest if-else is because the ability to return makes it much easier for IDE's to invert the outer if's for you as needed.

Of course if your are in the 1 return per function school, You can keep the if's unnested by making sure value that doesn't need more checks is always on the true side of the ternary (which is what the first method was doing, but with returns).

```
  if(!response.Item1)
    status = "Error"
  else if(task.IsCleanupTask)
    status = "Completed"
  else
    status = "New"

  return status
```